# Cannot reproduce Sony Vegas AVC output with ffmpeg

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg

I need to get a very specific H.264 elementary stream file for a decoder I own and actually the only software able to create such files is Vegas Pro.

In mediainfo this is the info I get about the stream:

```
Video
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Baseline@L3.1
Format settings                          : 3 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, RefFrames               : 3 frames
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=15
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Maximum bit rate                         : 2 000 kb/s
Width                                    : 960 pixels
Height                                   : 544 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate                               : 29.970 (30000/1001) FPS
Standard                                 : NTSC
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Color range                              : Limited
```

The file in particular is provided with Access Unit delimiters.
Is it possible to replicate the same output with ffmpeg?

Comment: Does this work in your decoder? `ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -profile:v baseline -g 15 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.264` I'm assuming your input width x height is 960x544 and frame rate is 30000/1001.

Comment: Seems to not work, in MediaInfo i also get Frame rate: Variable even if my input had a fixed framerate. Other differences in MediaInfo are absence of Bitrate info and no limited color range.

Comment: What's the preset you've used in Vegas?